# In Go can you create an interface or struct to define a map of functions which all have the same return type but unknown parameters?

Tags: go, go-echo

I am currently trying to use `a-h/templ` and create a map of the template functions that generates so that I can create a `Render` method.

With this templating library, you write a `.templ` file which then generated Go code where those templates are rendered as functions which all return the `templ.Component` type.

I am then trying to create a map of those functions and refer to them by a string so that another function can call them with just the name and then chain a method on to the returned `templ.Component` but can't seem to get this working as the unknown parameters don't allow this.

I am wondering if this is even possible?

I have the following code:
`base.templ`:

```
package templates

templ Hello(name string) {
  <div>Hello, { name }</div>
}

templ Greeting(person string, num int) {
  <div class="greeting">
    @Hello(person)
  </div>
  <div>You are the { num }th person</div>
}

templ Goodbye() {
  <div>Goodbye</div>
}
```

`renderer.go`:

```
package utils

import (
    "io"

    "github.com/a-h/templ"
    "github.com/labstack/echo/v4"
)

type Template struct {
    Components *map[string]func(...any) templ.Component
}

func (t *Template) GetComponents() (map[string]func(...any) templ.Component, bool) {
    if t == nil {
        return nil, false
    }

    return *t.Components, true
}

func (t *Template) Render(w io.Writer, name string, data interface{}, c echo.Context) error {

    comp, exists := t.GetComponents()
    
    if !exists {
        return nil
    }

    return comp[name](data).Render(c.Request().Context(), w)
}
```

(I know the `comp(data)` won't work here - this is something to be changed but not the current issue I'm asking for help)

`main.go`:

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"

    "github.com/a-h/templ"
    "github.com/labstack/echo/v4"
    templates "project-setup.com/web/components/layout"
    "project-setup.com/web/utils"
)

func main() {
    e := echo.New()

    comps := make(map[string]func(...any) templ.Component)
    t := templates.Greeting
    comps["greeting"] = &t

    e.GET("/hello", func(c echo.Context) error {

        e.Renderer = &utils.Template{
            Components: &comps,
        }

        return c.Render(200, "", "This guy")
    })


    e.GET("/", func(c echo.Context) error {     
        return c.String(http.StatusOK, "Hello, Root!")
    })
    e.Logger.Fatal(e.Start(":1323"))
}
```

This gives me an error for the line `comps["greeting"] = &t` in `main.go` saying `cannot use &t (value of type *func(person string, num int) templ.Component) as func(...any) templ.Component value in assignment  compiler(IncompatibleAssign)`.

I understand that they are technically different method signatures hence the issue, but is there no way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

`echo` has a Renderer you can assign to serve templated responses but no way to provide a function as the template rather than a string.

Comment: Function argument types are invariant, so you cannot do this directly (note you are also incorrectly taking the address if you function value, which will also always be the incorrect type). You could either make the functions the same type, or wrap all the component factories in simple `func(...any) templ.Component` function which just converts the types and calls the underlying implementation.